# Having trouble with nsRouterLink for Nativescript?

Tags: routes, angular2-nativescript

I recently have done a reinstall of nativescript and attempt to use `[nsRouterLink]="['/someDestination']"` and upon touching the link nothing occurs. Doing `(tap)="some function()"` combined with the router module gives me the result I want. I would prefer to understand what I have forgotten in implementing the `nsRouterLink` syntax. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Well, my error again.

I have been importing the NativescriptRouterModule into a separate file and thought it was sufficient for the entire module when I exported the list of routes and imported them into the my main module.  But adding the import of NativescriptRouterModule into the main module directly fixes everything. Nothing wrong here, just user error.